# Entering your home country with expired passport

Tags: passports, customs-and-immigration

Can you get in to your home country, if your passport is expired? Considering that your country doesn't have other IDs to prove your identity, you don't have time to get issued new passport on embassy in other country (e.g. death of relative) and you are traveling by land (I suppose no airline would let passenger enter the plane without valid ID)?

Is expired passport seen as "*minor prove*" of your identity, or is it same as you would try enter the country without any ID?

I understand that different countries have different rules, but what is general procedure?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: It depends on the country, for example Polish citizens cannot be denied entry to the country by the Constitution, and the Passport Act specifies that one can be allowed in on an expired passport. However, there will be problems with the carrier, as they would not allow you to board their vessel (bus/plane etc.).

Comment: Concerning the land borders, it will also depend on the country you are exiting. If there is an exit border control, you might not be allowed out of the country w/o valid ID, can be fined, or you will be fined and forced out, as you have no valid ID.

Comment: I've flagged this as too broad: a full answer would need a large table of country pairs.

Comment: @EdmundDantes Thank you, good point about exit border control, didn't think of that.

Comment: I agree with @EdmundDantes You may have got bigger problems departing with an expired passport *if the airline lets you check-in at all* (it wont), than entering your own country. You can also get in trouble even into getting in by land if stopped by police. Last year in a major event, there were borderline controls in the entry points by land to my home country (which have been open borders for years) not allowing anyone in without a valid id, even if they were nationals working abroad (it was all over the news). No valid ID, no entry.

Comment: I think you've discovered a reason to keep your passport(s) valid at all times.  One never knows when one will need it.

Comment: Some countries accept an expired passport as proof of citizenship and for entry, but some others do not. In cases where the country allows people to enter on an expired passport, this information is in Timatic, so airlines generally allow such people to fly home.